# How to read my radon system

Tags: radon, measuring

I have a radon system in my recently purchased home which looks like this:

[image: radon system]

However, I have no idea how to interpret what it is telling me. Can anyone provide clear and easy to follow instructions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually just a vacuum measurement system - used to show that there is negative pressure in the radon mitigation system drawing radon gas up and out of your home.

As long as the liquid in the right hand arm is higher than the left, then it is working.